# How to remove the two lowest grades from the listbox before the total grades are calculated?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to remove the two lowest grades from the listbox before the average and total of the grades is calculated using Visual Basic form application

I know I need to sort the array but I need to sort it after the listbox has been filled and before the average grade and total grade is calculated.

Please ignore the intMaxNumberOfEntries as 3. I will change it to 13 once I get the code working right.

```
   ' The btnEnterGrades_Click event accepts and displays up to 13 grades 
    ' and then calculates and displays the average grade for the student

    ' Declare and initialize variables

    Dim strGrade As String
    Dim intSizeOfArray As Integer = 3
    Dim decGrade(intSizeOfArray) As Decimal
    Dim decAverageGrade As Decimal
    Dim decTotalGrades As Integer = 0D
    Dim strInputMessage As String = "Enter the grade to be averaged #"
    Dim strInputHeading As String = "Enter Grades"
    Dim strNormalMessage As String = "Enter the grade to be averaged #"
    Dim strNonNumericError As String = "Error - Enter a number for the grade to be averaged"
    Dim strNegativeError As String = "Error - Enter a positive number for the grade to be averaged"
    Dim objWriter As New IO.StreamWriter("grades.txt")


    'Declare and initialize loop variables

    Dim strCancelClicked As String = ""
    Dim intMaxNumberOfEntries As Integer = 3
    Dim intNumberOfEntries As Integer = 1

    ' This loop allows the user to enter up to 13 grades for the student.
    ' The loop terminates when the user has entered 13 grades or the user 
    ' taps or clicks the Cancel button or the Close button in the InputBox


    '"Primimg the Loop" Accept some value and place it into the strGrade
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    strGrade = InputBox(strInputMessage & intNumberOfEntries, strInputHeading, " ")
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

    ' Determining if Grade entered is numeric. If so, add the item to the listbox
    Do Until intNumberOfEntries > intMaxNumberOfEntries Or strGrade = strCancelClicked

        If IsNumeric(strGrade) Then
            decGrade(intSizeOfArray) = Convert.ToDecimal(strGrade)
            If decGrade(intSizeOfArray) > 0 Then

                '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
                lstGrades.Items.Add(decGrade(intSizeOfArray))
                '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

             End If

                'Accumulator and Counter?? 
                decTotalGrades += decGrade(intSizeOfArray)
                intNumberOfEntries += 1 'or IntNumberOfEntries = intNumberOfEntries + 1
                strInputMessage = strNormalMessage
            Else
                strInputMessage = strNegativeError
            End If
        Else
            strInputMessage = strNonNumericError
        End If

        If intNumberOfEntries <= intMaxNumberOfEntries Then

            '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
            strGrade = InputBox(strInputMessage & intNumberOfEntries, strInputHeading, " ")
            '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

        End If

    Loop


    'Sort the Array
    Array.Sort(decGrade)
    'Put in descending order
    Array.Reverse(decGrade)

    'Drop 2 lowest scores of array
    ReDim decGrade(1)


    'Calculates and displays average student grade
    If intNumberOfEntries > 1 Then
        lblFinalAverageText.Visible = True
        decAverageGrade = decTotalGrades / (intNumberOfEntries - 1)
        lblFinalAverageText.Text = "The Final Average is: " &
            decAverageGrade.ToString("F1")
    Else
        MsgBox("No grade entered")
    End If
```

I want the program to remove the two lowest grades and I wrote code to sort the array and then sort by descending order and then redim to remove the two lowest grades but I realized the program is adding grades to the decTotalGrades before I start the sorting and redim process. I do not know how to rearrange this code for it to work.

Comment: obviously the grades are being added as getting input much before any attempt to Sort & `Redim` by the line  `lstGrades.Items.Add(decGrade(intSizeOfArray))`. also could not understand  how sorting takes place with line `Array.Sort` etc

Comment: Yes, I understand that adding the grades before sorting and using the redim is the problem. Array.Sort is what is shown as the example to sort arrays in my textbook. Can you tell me how to help fix the problem?

Comment: it is difficult to help without clear understanding of objective & lay out of the `Userform`. why you are trying to input it repeatedly (13 times) with input box (seems cumbersome).  You may use 13 text boxes on the `Userform` itself. or import from excel sheet.

Comment: The user is to input 13 grades for the semester or quarter. The program is supposed to remove the 2 lowest grades and then compute the average of the highest 11 grades. An array seems to be the best way to utilize the 13 grades which are input.

Comment: Layout of the user form is: btnEnterGrades for the user to enter the grades, lstGrades listbox to show the user grades entered and lblFinalAveragetext to show the Average grades of items in listbox without the two lowest grades averaged in. It will not let me add a picture of the form. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

You could refresh the list after collecting all grades and sorting/removing items.

```
'Collect grades.
Dim grades As New List(Of Decimal)
While grades.Count < 13
    Dim strGrade As String = InputBox("Enter the grade to be averaged #" &
                            grades.Count, "Enter Grades")

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(strGrade) Then
        Exit While
    Else
        Dim grade As Decimal
        If Decimal.TryParse(strGrade, grade) Then
            grades.Add(grade)
            lstGrades.Items.Add(grade)
        End If
    End If
End While

'Perform logic on the complete list of grades; Sort and remove.
'...

'Show the final list of grades.
lstGrades.Items.Clear()
For Each grade In grades
    lstGrades.Items.Add(grade)
Next
```